# JavaScript - Use a div tag to submit data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I saw a website the other day which had a very cool looking checkout system, and it occoured to me that this could not be done using just a regular form.

Basically they were using div tags as radio buttons, but there was no trickery involved of them hiding a radio button.

**Example HTML:**

```
<div class="checkout">


<div class="checkout-option" data="option-1">
<img src="example-product-1">
<h3>Example Product 1</h3>
</div>

<div class="checkout-option" data="option-2">
<img src="example-product-2">
<h3>Example Product 2</h3>
</div>

<div class="checkout-option" data="option-3">
<img src="example-product-3">
<h3>Example Product 3</h3>
</div>

<button id="submit-order">Checkout</button>





</div>
```

**So what do I want to happen?:**

1. User presses an option, for example option 2
2. User presses the checkout button
3. User is then redirected to whatever page

(And the data of the product they selected is sent to the server )

I have looked everywhere for a solution to this, there is no use of forms and I cannot understand how you would get this to work

Thanks for looking at my question!

Comment: Given that you want #3, why not use a standard form?  Just because you want to use the div stuff, doesn't mean you have to throw away the `<form>`

Comment: @Taplar Having a form is completely fine, I just want to know how I could send the data of their chosen product from a div tag using JavaScript? Using a div tag as an option allows for a very nicely styled selection box using CSS, where as this cannot be done with regular inputs (And even if it could, it doesn't seem to be a very professional thing to do)

Comment: I would suggest using a label, rather than a div.  The label can have an inner, hidden radio, that is selected when they click anything inside a label.  Then it's just a form submit

Comment: Don't ignore semantic elements, it isn't accessible.

Comment: @Taplar That would not be very professional, and is how my current system works, I simply hide a radio button using JavaScript, but other websites don't seem to need to do this, so there is a lot cleaner solution somewhere.

Comment: How is that not professional?  And the radio can be hidden with css.  Javascript isn't required for that part.

Comment: I just want to know how I would get the data="option-3" for example and then pass that to the server

Comment: See [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and [jQuery's data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xLptmp8n/2/  Super simple radio hiding

Comment: @serversideman Passing it to the server would be as simple as adding query string parameters onto a redirect with `window.location.replace()`

Comment: @mhodges How would I do this? You seem to have the right idea

Comment: @serversideman See [this article](https://perishablepress.com/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/). You can build your query string and then do `window.location.replace(myQueryString)` or you can use `window.location.href = myQueryString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you started in using DIVs in a "radio-button" style.

When someone clicks the Submit (Checkout) button, you can grab the value of the "active" div and create a form in a javascript variable. Then, use `.append()` to inject the form into the body of the webpage, and use `.submit()` to submit that just-created/just-injected form.

```js
$('.checkout-option').click(function(){
   $('.checkout-option').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
$('#submit-order').click(function(){
  var prod = $('.checkout-option.active h3').text();
  alert(prod);
  var myfrm = '<form id="theMyForm" action="somefile.html" method="post">\
     <input name="opt-selected" value="' +prod+ '" />\
     <input name="notice" value="You need to use backslash when breaking strings" />\
     </form>';
  $('body').append(myfrm);
  $('#theMyForm').submit();
});
```

```css
.checkout-option{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-right:10px;background:darkcyan;color:white;padding:10px;font-size:.9rem;border:1px solid transparent;}

.active{background:white;color:darkcyan;border:1px solid darkcyan;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkout">


<div class="checkout-option" data="option-1">
<img src="example-product-1">
<h3>Example Product 1</h3>
</div>

<div class="checkout-option" data="option-2">
<img src="example-product-2">
<h3>Example Product 2</h3>
</div>

<div class="checkout-option" data="option-3">
<img src="example-product-3">
<h3>Example Product 3</h3>
</div>

<button id="submit-order">Checkout</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Your code was very easy to read, thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

As @Taplar has mentioned, a `<form>` is best suited for this purpose.

Generally, the IDs correspond to data in a database. So, passing the ID is enough to reference the data. If you haven't structured things this way, you can include other hidden inputs to pass the necessary data.

Here's an example:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin:0 0 1em;
}
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.checkout-option input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked~h3 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<form action="//httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <div class="checkout">

    <label class="checkout-option">
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="1">
      <img src="example-product-1">
      <h3>Example Product 1</h3>
    </label>

    <label class="checkout-option">
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="2">
      <img src="example-product-2">
      <h3>Example Product 2</h3>
    </label>

    <label class="checkout-option">
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="3">
      <img src="example-product-3">
      <h3>Example Product 3</h3>
    </label>

    <button type="submit">Checkout</button>

  </div>
</form>
```